# How to Query in Sesame openrdf using SPARQL in Android?

Tags: android, rdf, sparql, sesame

I am trying to query an ontology with the Sesame API. The usual way of querying is not possible, as it gives an `UnsupportedQueryLanguageException`. No factory is available for query language SPARQL.

Eventually I am querying with:

```
SPARQLParser parser=new SPARQLParser();
ParsedQuery query=parser.parseQuery(queryString,null);

StatementPatternCollector collector=new StatementPatternCollector();
query.getTupleExpr().visit(collector);

List<StatementPattern> patterns=collector.getStatementPatterns();
```

When I display the result, it doesn't contain any statements; how can I display the statements?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Without some code for context, it's not clear what you're asking.  "Usual way of querying": what's this?

Comment: Out of interest: how did you come up with this code? Reason I ask is that I remember other people doing something similar, so I wonder if there is a tutorial somewhere online that mistakenly recommends this approach for querying...

Comment: As Joshua said in his answer: this code does not execute a query, it just parses a query string. It's completely the wrong approach. The problem you're facing is one of classpath configuration, not a programming issue, you should concentrate on solving that, instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a `UnsupportedQueryLanguageException` you probably don't have your classpath set up correctly.  Sesame loads things via the JDK ServiceLoader, so you're probably missing a jar file which contains the SPARQL stuff.

As far as your code snippet goes, that's not executing a SPARQL query.  That's walking the algebra of the parsed query and collecting any BGP's which are contained in the query.  I dont think that's what you were intending.

Double check your classpath to make sure you have the appropriate Sesame jars included and re-try the normal way of querying a Sesame Repository.

Comment: Given the specific error message in the exception, I'd say OP is missing either `sesame-queryparser-sparql-<version>.jar` or `sesame-queryparser-api-<version>.jar`, at the very least. Some general advice: use a dependency management tool to import your Sesame libraries, like Maven or Ivy.

Comment: Yes, i got this code online. The usual way i said is with the simple way of doing this as TupleQuery tuplequery=con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString); TupleQueryResult result=tuplequery.evaluate().

Comment: I am doing it for an Android application. If you remember i ask the similar question for loading file. That problem was solved by writing TurtleParser parser=new TurtleParser() and then using this parser in code. After, i got the problem with Query and i thought may be it could be solved in a similar way.

Comment: I now used Maven in Eclipse for my Android Application but now its unable to run ClassNotFoundException on Main Activity.

Comment: @user3556249 if you solved that other question, would you be so kind as to actually add your solution to that question as an answer there? That way, others with a similar problem can more easily find it. Thanks.

Comment: ok but i am still not sure whether its the right way how i did. This was the reason of not adding that. Kindly tell me the solution of this query problem. I found a similar question and your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500599/sparql-parser-for-java-code but in my case SailTupleQuery() is giving problem.